# Subdomínio para arquivos, Otimização do Site

Tags: otimização, subdomínio

Bom, ouvi falar que para maior numero de downloads em paralelo a indicação é coloca-las em um subdomínio, e até um fato de que os cookies não irem na requisição também já deixaria mais rápida.

Enfim, verdade ou mito, até onde essa prática pode ajudar? (JS, CSS) é valido também?

Answer (score 6):

Depende de varios fatores,

1- se o subdominio continuar a ficar no mesmo servidor que o website, eu acho que nao ira arreceber optimizacao nenhuma.

2- se utilizar algum tipo de tecnologia para proteger o seu website como a `cloudflare` podera sim atrasar os seus downloads ou ate mesmo optimizar, tudo depende de onde o utilizador esta localizado e a sua velocidade de Internet.

3- Nao acho que as cookies poderam atrasar os downloads, nao vejo razao para a mesma acontecer.

Basicamente, se quiser ter um site que faz upload dos ficheiro rapido para os utilizadores, sim poderas criar um subdominio em que o subdominio aponte para outro servidor teu, em que esse servidor apenas sirva para o download e upload de ficheiros. Ai teras um website suberbo em que os download poderam ser super rapidos exemplo (`downloads1.seuwebsite.com` podera apontar para 1 servidor seu `downloads2.seuwebsite.com` podera apontar para outro servidor seu) normalmente essa tecnica e utilizada quando a 1 maquina nao tem mais espaco disponivel, ou ate mesmo 1 outro servidor com internet super rapida para ficheiros de maior porte.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cookies atrasam o download sim. Quando uma requisição é feita para `subdominio.meusite.com`, o browser envia (faz upload) de todos os cookies existentes em `subdominio.meusite.com` e `meusite.com`, e no response também é feito o download desses dados ([+ detalhes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1063760/1574059)). Por isso grandes sites usam dominios diferentes (não subdominios) para servir conteúdo estático, como aplicativos Google, que usam `googleusercontent.com`.

Answer (score 5):

Se for no mesmo servidor o subdominio, não irá ajudar em nada, pois continuará baixando do mesmo local!

O interessante para seu caso seria contratar uma CDN(Content Distribution Network), assim você poderá saber a localização da pessoa e indicar o servidor mais próximo com seus arquivos sem nenhum trabalho braçal!

A CDN pode ser a CloudFlare, pode ser a MaxCDN e várias outras empresas como a Amazon que oferecem produtos parecidos com CDN ou com funções bem similares aos de uma!

Minificar os JS e CSS podem ajudar sim a velocidade!

Esta prática pode te ajudar a indexar no Google em uma posição mais alta, atrair mais pessoas a seu site por ser rápido e dispor de maior rapidez para qualquer mudança!

Comment: então quanto mais perto de você os servidores estiverem mais rápido será o download?

Comment: claro que sim, mas tambem depende da localizacao do seu [ISP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fornecedor_de_acesso_%C3%A0_internet) e a sua velocidade de conexao que voce tem entre ele.

Answer (score 1):

Por meio do plugin YSlow do Firefox (depende de ter o Firebug também) cheguei a esta página:
http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/
. É de 2007, pode ter mudado bastantes coisas desde a publicação, mas apresenta um estudo exatamente sobre o que perguntou.

Em resumo:
Parte do principio que aumentando o número de domínios deve melhorar o tempo até carregar todos os elementos requisitados, porque a especificação HTTP/1.1 sugere que os navegadores deveriam baixar dois componentes em paralelo por hostname (apontado por Henrique acima). Este limite pode ser mudado via configuração tanto no I.E. quanto no Firefox (não há informação de outros), mas quem mexe no servidor não vai configurar nenhum navegador de cliente, e o modo de configurar não é muito user-friendly.

Só que os resultados do teste dele não foram exatamente os esperados. Tem dois testes, 20 imagens cada um, sendo um imagens pequenas e outro médias. Ambos tiveram melhoria no aumento de 1 para 2 hosts, porém o de imagens pequenas não teve impacto significativo ao aumentar mais o número de hosts e o de imagens médias teve impacto negativo! Sendo que com 3 hosts já ficava pior que com 1 host. No final ele chega à conclusão que o melhor deve ser de 2 a 4 hosts.

O CDN que o Vinicius citou ajuda bastante também, tentando diminuir a distância entre o navegador do cliente e a fonte do conteúdo requisitado.

Outro motivo para colocar mais hosts seria ter hostname(s) com conteúdo dinâmico e outro(s) com conteúdo estático, usando cabeçalho de expiração de conteúdo para que seja gravado em cache, mas isto pode ser feito em um único hostname por meio de configuração com o módulo mod_expires do apache por exemplo.

Se a intenção é saber o que melhorar em uma página para deixa-la mais rápida ou leve, o Firefox com o Firebug e o YSlow pode ajudar bastante, não conheço ferramenta semelhante em outros navegadores, mas deve haver.

Se tiver recursos disponíveis para fazer testes, o Safari (pelo menos no OS X) tem um recurso muito bom de cronometrar o tempo que leva ao carregar uma página indicando cada ação. Não estou certo, mas acho que já vi isto no Chrome no Windows também.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um problema do HTTP 1.1, que usamos atualmente ele é um protocolo sequencial. Isso quer dizer que, quando abrimos a conexão, podemos fazer 1 request por vez. Vai 1 request, esperamos, chega a resposta; só aí podemos disparar outro request.

Para tentar diminuir o impacto negativo desse comportamento, os navegadores com HTTP 1.1 abrem mais de uma conexão ao mesmo tempo. Hoje em dia esse número costuma ser de 4 a 8 conexões simultâneas por hostname.

O HTTP 2.0 já vai ter multiplexing, evitando de fazer essas gambiarras que fazemos de subdominios, mas você já pode usar o SPDY que é um protocolo feito pela google, que já tem essa opção, porem para instala-lo você tem que ter HTTPS instalado no seu servidor.

E deixando os arquivos CSS e JS em um arquivo só ajuda sim, pois só vai fazer uma requisição por arquivo.